# IKImageView weird Crash in mountain lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ikimageview

I have an `IKImageView` and `NSSlider`. I dragged and dropped a Image into `IKImageView` and used `NSSlider` for zooming the Image. I am getting the crash while zoom in and zoom out the image in random.
This is the Message I am getting in console.

```
ImageIO: ImageProviderReleaseInfoCallback $$$ ImageProviderReleaseInfoCallback: cookie without releaseInfo - leaking

IKImage(526,0x100587000) malloc: *** error for object 0x100653d60: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

(lldb)
```

This is my code
**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet IKImageView *imageView;
}
- (IBAction)sliderScliked:(id)sender;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (IBAction)sliderScliked:(id)sender {

    [imageView setZoomFactor:[sender doubleValue]];
}
```

**XCode Project**

Here is the xCode Project.
http://goo.gl/p9W3y

I would like to solve this error as soon as possible on this sample app.
thank you in advance.

IA

Comment: "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"